# Is there a way to add two different colors on a route (path) if I have 3 wayPoints? leaflet routing machine

Tags: javascript, orm, routes, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

If I call a segment as line/route between two way-points. and suppose if I have three way-points then can I have a different color on each segment? If so how can I achieve it? thanks